# flutter app can not connect to a webSocket

Tags: flutter, dart, websocket, stomp

I am building a flutter app which needs to connect to the server and exchange data using websocket. The server is in JAVA and using SockJs and Stomp  to implement this functionality.

I am using Stomp dart client and webSocket packages from pub.dev/packages.
This is the part of my code where I am trying to connect :

```
  clientConnect() async {
    String cookie = await storage.read(key: "cookie");
    final stompClient = StompClient(
        config: StompConfig(url: 'ws://192.168.0.13:8080/....', onConnect: onConnect,
            webSocketConnectHeaders: {"cookie": cookie }));
    stompClient.activate();
  }
```

The problem I am facing is, my flutter app is not able to connect to the server and throws the this error.

```
 WebSocketException: Connection to 'http://192.168.0.12:8080/....' was not upgraded to websocket
```

Comment: Did you find the solution ?

Answer (score 2):

Late answer (maintainer of the stomp package):

Since you seem to be using StompJS on the java-side you need to use the special StompJS config in the client. Here is the example from the documentation:

https://pub.dev/packages/stomp_dart_client#use-stomp-with-sockjs

```
StompClient client = StompClient(
    config: StompConfig.SockJS(
        url: 'https://yourserver',
        onConnect: onConnectCallback
    )
);
```